# Error installing an npm library with jspm

Tags: npm, jspm

I'm trying to install [react-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker) with jspm and I'm getting this error:

```
$ jspm install npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker
Password:
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker
     Updating registry cache...
     Downloading npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker@0.0.21
     Looking up npm:babel-runtime
     Looking up npm:classnames
     Looking up npm:moment
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap
     Looking up npm:react
     Downloading npm:classnames@2.1.5
     Downloading npm:react-bootstrap@0.16.1
     Downloading npm:moment@2.10.6

warn Error on download for npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker
     Error: ENOENT, link '/Users/me/.jspm/packages/npm/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker@0.0.21/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/lib/DateTimeField.js'
         at Error (native)

err  Error downloading npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker.

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

I can see that it's failing because there is no directory `react-bootstrap-datetimepicker` in

`/Users/me/.jspm/packages/npm/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker@0.0.21/`.

However, there is

`/Users/me/.jspm/packages/npm/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker@0.0.21/lib/DateTimeField.js`.

Does the react-bootstrap-datetimepicker code need to be modified so that it will work with jspm?  Any other ideas what is causing this?

I logged an issue [here](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/112).

Comment: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/284

Comment: @Lilp, Thanks for the tip.  That issue was from quite a while ago, and I'm not seeing how it relates to this problem.  Can you give a little more specifics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in jspm/npm.  Here's [the issue](https://github.com/jspm/npm/issues/103).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is solved:

```
jspm install npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker
     Updating registry cache...
     Downloading npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker@0.0.21
     Looking up npm:babel-runtime
     Looking up npm:classnames
     Looking up npm:moment
     Looking up npm:react-bootstrap
     Looking up npm:react
     Downloading npm:classnames@2.2.0
     Downloading npm:react@0.14.1
     Looking up npm:envify
     Looking up npm:fbjs
     Downloading npm:react-bootstrap@0.16.1
ok   Installed npm:moment@^2.8.2 (2.10.6)
ok   Installed npm:classnames@^2.1.2 (2.2.0)
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-process
     Downloading npm:envify@3.4.0
     Looking up npm:through
     Looking up npm:jstransform
     Downloading npm:fbjs@0.3.2
     Looking up npm:core-js
     Looking up npm:loose-envify
     Looking up npm:promise
     Looking up npm:ua-parser-js
     Looking up npm:whatwg-fetch
ok   Installed npm:envify@^3.0.0 (3.4.0)
     Downloading npm:through@2.3.8
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-assert
     Looking up github:systemjs/plugin-json
     Downloading npm:promise@7.0.4
     Looking up npm:asap
     Downloading npm:whatwg-fetch@0.9.0
     Downloading npm:ua-parser-js@0.7.9
     Downloading npm:jstransform@10.1.0
     Looking up npm:base62
     Looking up npm:esprima-fb
     Looking up npm:source-map
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-path
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-fs
ok   Installed npm:through@~2.3.4 (2.3.8)
ok   Installed npm:whatwg-fetch@^0.9.0 (0.9.0)
     Looking up npm:process
     Downloading npm:asap@2.0.3
     Downloading npm:source-map@0.1.31
     Looking up npm:amdefine
     Downloading npm:base62@0.1.1
ok   Installed npm:ua-parser-js@^0.7.9 (0.7.9)
ok   Installed npm:promise@^7.0.3 (7.0.4)
     Downloading npm:esprima-fb@13001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb
     Looking up npm:assert
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-stream
     Downloading npm:loose-envify@1.1.0
     Looking up npm:js-tokens
     Downloading npm:amdefine@1.0.0
     Looking up npm:path-browserify
ok   Installed npm:asap@~2.0.3 (2.0.3)
     Looking up npm:util
ok   Installed npm:jstransform@^10.0.1 (10.1.0)
ok   Installed npm:base62@0.1.1 (0.1.1)
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-domain
     Looking up npm:inherits
ok   Installed npm:amdefine (1.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:fbjs@^0.3.1 (0.3.2)
ok   Installed npm:loose-envify@^1.0.0 (1.1.0)
     Downloading github:jspm/nodelibs-domain@0.1.0
     Downloading npm:js-tokens@1.0.2
     Looking up npm:stream-browserify
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-module
ok   Installed github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@^0.1.0 (0.1.0)
     Looking up npm:readable-stream
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-util
     Looking up npm:domain-browser
     Downloading github:jspm/nodelibs-module@0.1.0
ok   Installed npm:react (0.14.1)
ok   Installed npm:stream-browserify@^1.0.0 (1.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:esprima-fb@13001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb (13001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb)
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-events
     Downloading npm:domain-browser@1.1.4
ok   Installed npm:js-tokens@^1.0.1 (1.0.2)
     Looking up npm:core-util-is
     Looking up npm:isarray
     Looking up npm:string_decoder
ok   Installed npm:source-map@0.1.31 (0.1.31)
ok   Installed npm:readable-stream@^1.0.27-1 (1.1.13)
ok   Installed npm:react-bootstrap@^0.16.1 (0.16.1)
ok   Installed npm:isarray@0.0.1 (0.0.1)
ok   Installed npm:domain-browser@^1.1.3 (1.1.4)
ok   Installed npm:core-util-is@~1.0.0 (1.0.1)
ok   Installed npm:string_decoder@~0.10.0 (0.10.31)
     Looking up github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer
ok   Installed github:jspm/nodelibs-domain@^0.1.0 (0.1.0)
     Looking up npm:events
ok   Installed github:jspm/nodelibs-events@^0.1.1 (0.1.1)
ok   Installed npm:events@1.0.2 (1.0.2)
ok   Installed github:jspm/nodelibs-module@^0.1.0 (0.1.0)
     Looking up npm:buffer
ok   Installed github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@^0.1.0 (0.1.0)
     Looking up npm:base64-js
     Looking up npm:ieee754
     Looking up npm:is-array
ok   Installed npm:buffer@^3.0.1 (3.5.1)
ok   Installed npm:ieee754@^1.1.4 (1.1.6)
ok   Installed npm:is-array@^1.0.1 (1.0.1)
ok   Installed npm:base64-js@0.0.8 (0.0.8)
ok   Installed react-bootstrap-datetimepicker as npm:react-bootstrap-datetimepicker@^0.0.21 (0.0.21)
ok   Install tree has no forks.

ok   Install complete.
```

Running with jspm@0.16.3 on a newly-initialized project.

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently it was a bug in jspm-npm.